# manytomany: ImportError: cannot import name '...' from partially initialized module '...' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: django

I'm facing this problem with a ManyToManyField in Django
.
Import Error: cannot import Room from partially initialized module.

file contact.py:

```
from django.db import models

from accounting.models.account import Account


class Contact(models.Model):

id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
account = models.ManyToManyField(Account, through='contactaccount')
```

file account.py

```
from django.db import models

from .accountgroup import AccountGroup
from .accountclass import AccountClass

class Account(models.Model):

id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
code = models.IntegerField()
class_account = models.ForeignKey(AccountClass, models.DO_NOTHING,default=0)
group_account = models.ForeignKey(AccountGroup, models.DO_NOTHING,default=0)
```

file contactaccount.py

```
from django.db import models

from accounting.models.account import Account

from .contact import Contact



class ContactAccount(models.Model):

account = models.ForeignKey(Account,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I can' find the solution

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in `contactaccount.py` is instead of importing the other models, you can reference them like this: `"your_app.Account"` and `"your_other_app.Contact"` in the foreign key field. Like this:

```
class ContactAccount(models.Model):

    account = models.ForeignKey("your_app.Account",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contact = models.ForeignKey("your_other_app.Contact",  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```